# Google Colab error: TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

My code:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=2050,2050")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
```

when I ever run the code it keeps saying the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-8904e7337232> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
      5 chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
----> 6 driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)

TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'
```

I tried the other solutions here, but I am using google Collab, I think there are extra things I should do to further fix this?

I need to understand what is the problem

Comment: Hello Michael, I tried that solution it did not work for some reason, maybe because I am using google collab? I am confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed `chromedriver` inside `Chrome` constructor as a first argument, where constructor expects `options` to be passed.

Remove first argument and issue would be fixed.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=2050,2050")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: I have just tried it for some reason it gives me this error:

NameError: name 'chrome_options' is not defined

Comment: @King are you code the same as you provided? Do you have this line: `chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()`?

Comment: Yes Yaro, I am using the exact same code I posted here, do you think you can share your code if possible?

Comment: @King see updated snippet

Comment: Yaro your solution worked thank you mate, but I another problem appeared :), I update the problem on my question, if you have a moment can you take a look please? sorry I am a newbie

Comment: I am not sure how to edit the question, here is the problem yaro: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 90
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.96 with binary path /root/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/116.0.5845.96/chrome

Comment: I know I need to update my chromedriver, I already went to the website and downloaded the latest version, I am putting it in my folder but still for some reason it's not locating it, I am confused

Comment: How I will pass proxies with selenium